# How to get the values of a table columns other than primary key

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, netzke

For getting the value of the primary key of the selected row, we can use `record.get('id')` in **extjs**. How to get the values of other columns (Say, if I have a column named **name** or **t_id**). In my case when I alert `record.get('id')` it gives the exact value whereas alerting `record.get('t_id')` shows **undefined**.

Thanks.

**Update:**

I am getting the result for `record.get('name')`. Only the **foreign key** `t_id` is not working.

Comment: Are u having 't_id' defined in your store's model.

Comment: What you meant by defining? In my rails model it is already there.

Comment: post your code, so that we can able to find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check certain thing @ejo.

```
1. As @Daemon said you need to check whether you had defined 't_id' in your store feilds or in model. 
2. Second, you need to check whether you are sending the 't_id' value from backend.
3. third, if you use grid.getview option, check whether that t_id has been mapped to grid.
```

The most important one, please post your code, so that we can able to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah! The foreign keys in grid are always missing in my experience. Please try defining a hidden field for that foreign key(not tested yet):

```
column :t_id do |c|
  c.hidden = true
end
```